# HTML5 semantics & outlines

Tags: html, semantics

I just recently discovered the whole HTML outline thing and found this great online [HTML5 outliner tool](http://gsnedders.html5.org/outliner/). Now I'm trying to accomplish a semantically proper simple HTML page with outline that should look like this:

1. Page

   1. Nav
   2. Main
   3. Sub

      1. Aside
   4. Footer

And render a page like this:

```
| --- NAV ----------------- |
|      content              |
| --- MAIN ---------------- |
|      content              |
| --- SUB ----------------- |
|      content      | aside |
| --- FOOTER -------------- |
|      content              |
```

The HTML looks as follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Title</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="page">

        <header class="page--header">
            <hgroup>
                <h1>page</h1>
                <h2>subtitle</h2>
            </hgroup>
            <nav>
                <h1>Nav</h1>
                <ul>
                    <li>link 1</li>
                    <li>link 2</li>
                    <li>link 3</li>
                    <li>link 4</li>
                    <li>link 5</li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </header><!-- .page-header -->

        <section class="page--main">
            <h1>Main</h1>                
        </section><!-- .page-main -->

        <section class="page--sub">
            <h1>Sub</h1>
            <aside>
                <h1>Aside</h1>
                <p>Advertisement block</p>
            </aside><!-- aside -->                
        </section><!-- .page-sub -->

        <footer>
            <h1>Footer</h1>                
        </footer><!-- footer -->

    </div><!-- .page -->
</body>
</html>
```

That makes the outline look like this:

1. Page

   1. Nav
   2. Main
   3. Sub

      1. Aside
2. Footer

How should I alter the HTML to keep it semantically correct while getting the outline mentioned above? How come `footer` is not outlined on same level as those top-level section elements (ie. main & sub) even when they all are siblings with same heading-level?

Confused, and any help, criticism or suggestions are welcome, thanks!

Comment: Consecutive hyphens inside a comment are invalid, e.g., `<!-- .page--sub -->` is invalid but `<!-- .page- -sub -->` is not.

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing this, never thought about that!

Comment: That's ok, there's always time to learn!

Comment: Just change the `<h1>` in the footer to an `<h2>`. It not only works from an outline perspective, but strange as it may seem, is semantically correct too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use ranked `<h1>` to  `<h6>` headings instead of all `<h1>`s. [source](http://html5doctor.com/interview-steve-faulkner-html5-editor-new-doctor/#comment-32325)
2. Wrap main content inside `<main>` element. Remember to set `main { display: block }` for cross browser compatibility.
3. Put sidebar container (`<aside>`) inside `<main>` as `<aside>` is a complementary content of `<main>`.
4. Remove the `<h1>` inside `<footer>` as `<footer>` is not a sectioning element so it doesn't need a heading.

Brief example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <header role="banner">
        <hgroup>
            <h1>page</h1>
            <h2>subtitle</h2>
        </hgroup>
        <nav role="navigation">
            <h2>Nav</h2>
            <ul>
                <li>link 1</li>
                <li>link 2</li>
                <li>link 3</li>
                <li>link 4</li>
                <li>link 5</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>

    <main role="main">

        <!-- main content goes here -->
        <section id="example">
            <h2>Example</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum</p>
        </section>
        <!-- main content goes here -->

        <aside role="complementary">
            <h2>Aside</h2>
            <article id="ad">
                <h3>Ad</h3>
                <p>Advertisement block</p>
            </article>
        </aside>    

    </main>

    <footer role="contentinfo">
        <p><small>&copy; <time>2013</time> Website Name</small></p>
    </footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `header` nor `footer` will create bullet points in an outline. The main sectioning elements are: `nav`, `section`, `article`, and `aside`.

You should probably check out: http://html5doctor.com/outlines/